# Changing indentation style in atom editor (javascript code)

Tags: javascript, formatting, ide, indentation, atom-editor

I've used microsoft's vscode for some months, but since 2 updates the indentation is broken **for me**, without a way to fix it. I therefore consider switching to atom. I was working with atom before, and never had this problem, but now it seems to have the ***same*** (wrong for me) behaviour as vscode:

```
if (xxx) // press enter here and type 'something();'
```

should result in

```
if (xxx)
    something();
```

but it results in

```
if (xxx)
something();
```

It will work completely finde if you add `{ }`, but without them its like the above.

How can I fix this in atom? The basic identation settings don't seem to cover this.

Comment: Switch to Sublime?

Comment: Unfortunately I need a `Node.js` debugger too, so its not only about editing source code. And I don't want to use chrome for this.

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing this si to always use `{}` (also because I'm using [linter-standard-js](https://atom.io/packages/linter-js-standard)) That way, you type

`if (myCondition) {}`

When you return between the accolades, you get the following

```
if (myCondition) {
  // indented and here you go
}
```

Comment: Okay cool, but my way of doing it is to not use `{ }` around single-line `if`s :)

Comment: Oh snap, I just read it on your original post. I used to omit them too but forced myself not to since I started coding the standard style. And I could see the benefit later. No cons (really doesn't takes more time than not using them) but here are the pros I figured : better code readability and adding lines in the condition became faster as `{}` are already there (think of the usual `console.log('is my condition ok ?')`

Comment: One rule that I have is to only omit parentheses when everything is in one line, ie `if(cond) [tab] func();` is fine.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 this rule is also in standardjs so I totally agree ! `if (cond) doSomething()`

Comment: So the conclusion is that there is no way to change the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra conditions for Atom to change the indent level in your `config.cson` file, following the lead of [the packages that define those conditions](https://github.com/atom/language-javascript/blob/master/settings/language-javascript.cson) in the first place. Add the following to the top level of `config.cson` and Atom will automatically add a level of indentation after a line that matches the regular expression `if\s*\(.*\)$`. If you already have a `.source.js` entry, make sure to change that instead of just pasting this bit in.

```
'.source.js':
  editor:
    increaseIndentPattern: '(?x)
        \\{ [^}"\']* $
      | \\[ [^\\]"\']* $
      | \\( [^)"\']* $
      | if\\s*\\(.*\\)$
      '
```

Comment: Okay seems to work, but the corresponding `decreaseIndentPattern` can not be expressed probably, since it would need to reference to line with the `if`, right?
So therefore I have the problem on the other side now.

Comment: Correct. Either way you're going to have to press `tab` or `delete` once.